# Is there PDF library for PHP to print an image on existing pdf?

Tags: php, pdf-generation

I'm searching for pdf library, preferably open source, which will print a image on an existing pdf. I looked at [Haru](http://libharu.sourceforge.net/examples.html) but it edits only creates pdf from scratch and they don't intend to add pdf editing feature anytime in the future. PHP library would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework will print onto an existing pdf, provided it's a version 1.5 or before (I think, not 100% sure on the pdf version, could be 1.4).

Read more here - http://devzone.zend.com/article/2525

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at FPDI (http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/) which can extend TCPDF or FPDF and allows you to load PDF's as templates.

Comment: can you guide me to set it up.